# I get undefined from calling a service in a component Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, service, dependency-injection

I have created an interface and a service in which this service is responsible for getting some data from API, but when I try to call that from a component, it returns undefined to me.
these are my services and my component
(I have also noticed that the function within the service returns void, and I have provided them in the app.module )

```
@Injectable()

export class TasksService {
    compeletedTasks: Task[];
    constructor(public http: Http) {}

    getCompeletedTasks(): Observable<Task[]>{
        return this.http.get("http://localhost:4000/api/compeleted");
    }
```

and this is my component:

```
import { TasksService } from '../../services/tasks.service';

export class DoneTaskItemsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private tasksService:TasksService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.tasksService.getCompeletedTasks().
        subscribe(response => console.log(response))
    }
```

So any solution for that? I need to use the compeletedTasks on the template, but for now, when I log them on the console, I get undefined.

Comment: changing "private" to "public" in service constructor is not helping either

Comment: You defined arguement in getCompeletedTasks(compeletedTasks) method but while calling you are not passing any argument???? Try to console.log in getCompeletedTasks method & check whether it is consoling or not??

Comment: no, it was just my mistake, I edited this now

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: and yes when I log both the method and array in service I get the result I want, but when I try to log in on my component, I get undefined

Comment: I am using Angular 8

Comment: Try @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

Comment: You r getting undefined because you are not returning anything from function

Comment: Why are you using http, Can't you use httpClient ? check this
 https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#enable-http-services

Comment: I have tried that @TomShaw before but no luck, I have provided it in the app.module as well and yet no result

Comment: You need to return a promise or the subscription.

Comment: @Plochie I will edit my post with the return but I have no luck there it still says undefined

Comment: Please check the posted answer. You need to return observable and then subscribe to it in component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Challappan says you need to use httpClient instead of http for making api requests.

Try to change code like below.

```
getCompeletedTasks(){
   return this.http.get("http://localhost:4000/api/compeleted");
}
```

In component like below.

```
compeletedTasks: Task[]

ngOnInit() {
    this.tasksService.getCompeletedTasks().subscribe(response => {
         this.completedTasks = response;
    });
}
```

This link might help.

[angular httpClient api example medium](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular-2305b8fd654b)

Comment: this is what I get in the component 
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you mean 'unsubscribe'?
'unsubscribe' is declared here.

Comment: thanks, I just figured it out how to handle the above comment thing 
thanks for your help